# What is the result of the the following infinite product?

Tags: calculus

$\eta\in(0,1)$ is a constant. What is the result of the the following infinite product:
$$J:=\Pi_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1+2^k}{\eta+2^k}.$$
Obvious $J\geq1$. On the other hand, since $\frac{1+2^k}{\eta+2^k}=1+\frac{1-\eta}{\eta+2^k}$ and $$I:=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-\eta}{\eta+2^k} \leq(1-\eta)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}=1-\eta$$ converges, hence $J$ is also converges. I want to know what is the result (Does $J$ depends on the value of $\eta$ )? Thanks!

Comment: Obviously the value of $J$ depends on the value of $\eta$! If $\eta_1 < \eta_2$ you have $$\frac{1+2^k}{\eta_1 + 2^k} > \frac{1+2^k}{\eta_2 + 2^k}$$ so that $$J( \eta_1) > J ( \eta_2 )$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure it depends on $\eta$. You can try computing the value numerically for different $\eta$ and see for yourself. Though this would not exactly be rigorous. In this spirit, here is a hint:

**Hint:**

$$
\sum_{k=1}^∞ \frac{1}{\eta + 2^k} = \frac{ψ_{(1/2)}^0\left(-\frac{\ln(-\eta/2)}{\ln(2)}\right) - \ln(2)}{\eta \ln(2)}
$$

Where $ψ_{q}(z)$ is the Digamma-log function. [More details here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F(a%2B2%5Ek)+from+k%3D1+to+infinity)

Also note that:

$$
J(\eta) = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1+2^k}{\eta+2^k}
$$
Then:
$$
\frac{dJ}{d\eta}=-J\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\eta+2^k}
$$

Note that if the left hand side happened to be zero, then that would be the case of $J$ not depending on $\eta$.